# How to map a domain name like www.something.com to Hosted ASP.NET Core 6 api as Windows Service using Kestrel server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-services, .net-6.0, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

In my current project. The previous dev has hosted an asp.net core 6 Web API as a window service using Kestrel on azure window virtual machine. I have to create a replica on the same API; please take a reference to the below links.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

https://dev.to/sumitkharche/how-to-host-asp-net-core-3-1-web-applications-as-windows-service-52k2

I can create, build and install the API as a window service in an azure virtual machine and local machine as well, which also works in localhost: port.

Now I want to map that API to some domains like [www.someting.com](http://www.someting.com). But cannot find a way how to map a domain.

In this window service way, API hosting is pretty new to me, and there is also not enough documentation that can help me.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why are you hosting on a VM? That's the hardest way to host :). Anyways can I assume you bought a domain, have a public IP address for the VM, and you have firewall rules setup to not block port 80?

Comment: Right, I am currently using 9006 ports for the new API service; another four APIs are hosted on the same VM. But not sure how the previous dev has hosted that.

Comment: This isn't really a .NET or a kestrel question per-se. There are some other things that need to be understand before .NET comes into the picture.

- Do you have a load balancer running on port 80 or 443 already?

Comment: Not sure, I have to check and will let you know

Comment: It typically goes like this:
- Expose port 80 or 443 (http or https) (only one process can own these ports)
- Make sure the application is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0 or ::)
- Make sure there's no firewall blocking them
- Get the public IP address for the VM (if you're on azure you need to provision a public IP)
- Map the domain name to your IP address (A record, CNAME etc)
- Profit

Comment: If you happen to have other sites running on that same VM already then its likely you have to replace the first 2 steps with configuring the reverse proxy for your new web app.